# login Alert at AWS Root Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I am trying to create a policy that if AWS ROOT account try to login, it should sent me alert.

What will be the best way to do this.

Thanks
Malik Adeel Imtiaz

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring CloudTrail/Eventbridge events  and triggering notification action after Root login.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-aws-console-sign-in-events.html

Here is a link to free workshop which tesches how to set up an alarm using Cloudwatch:
https://catalog.workshops.aws/startup-security-baseline/en-US/b-securing-your-account/7-configurealarms/7-2-root-account-use-alarm

Comment: Do i need to create only, POLICY and add the root account in it?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-aws-console-sign-in-events.html#cloudtrail-signin-root-mfa

Comment: No, policies are not a right tool for that. See a link to workshop in an edited answer. You can use Cloudwatch for that.

Comment: To make answers more useful, please include the relevant parts directly in the answer. Links can go missing.